# Postgres How to keep counties with no data in the query results

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I have a query that counts the number of brokerages, agent, and unaffiliated agents in a county. Not every county has brokerages and agents and those counties are currently excluded from the results. I want to all the counties to be in the results regardless of the number of agents/brokerages there.
My current query is:

```
with locations_cte as
(
    select 
        lpad(cbsa.zip,5,'0') as zip,
        cbsa.st,
        cbsa.county
    from cbsa_locations cbsa
)
,
brokerage_count_cte as 
(
    select 
        distinct cb.county,
        cb.st,
        count(distinct bcz.brokerage_code) as brokerageCount
    from brokerage_coverage_zips bcz
    left join locations_cte cb on cb.zip = bcz.zip
    group by cb.st,cb.county

)
,
agent_count_cte as 
(
    select 
        distinct cb.county,
        cb.st,
        --COALESCE(pup.brokerage_code,'NO-BROKERAGE-CODE') AS brokerage_code,
        count(distinct puz.profile_id) as agentCount,
        count(distinct case when pup.brokerage_code is not null then puz.profile_id end) as BAagentCount
    from profile_coverage_zips puz
    left join locations_cte cb on cb.zip = puz.zip
    join partner_user_profiles pup on pup.id = puz.profile_id
    where pup.verification_status = 'Verified-Verified'
    group by cb.county, cb.st--, pup.brokerage_code

)
select 
    distinct cb.county,
    cb.st,
    bcc.brokerageCount,
    acc.agentCount,
    acc.BAagentCount,
    acc.agentCount - acc.BAagentCount as UnaffiliatedAgentCount
from locations_cte cb
join brokerage_count_cte bcc on bcc.st = cb.st and bcc.county = cb.county
join agent_count_cte acc on acc.st = cb.st and acc.county = cb.county
-- order by bcc.brokerageCount ASC
```

and when I include the last line of the query the lowest county brokerageCount is 1 whereas I want the counties with 0 to show up as well.
Tables are as follows:

cbsa_locations:

- contains, zip,county,state

brokerage_coverage_zips

- brokerage_code, row for each zip, only contains location data for areas a brokerage covers

profile_coverage_zips

- same as brokerage_coverage_zips but for an agent instead of brokerage

Comment: `distinct` is redundant where you're already grouping. You would need both left joins from `locations` to brokers/agents to keep the unrepresented counties.

Answer (score 0):

Use LEFT OUTER JOINs instead of INNER JOINS.